Create a New Workbook With LineChart,then I opened it with office Excel,but office excel will repair it ,then my LineChart will disappear
Describe the bug
Create a New Workbook With LineChart,then I opened it with office Excel,but office excel will repair it ,then my LineChart will disappear
Here's the image
enter image description here
Here's the code
static void InsertLineChartInSpreadsheet(){
string docName = "D:\\408064545445-231008161302-A-1-1-2.xlsx";
Dictionary\<string, List\<Tuple\<string, int\>\>\> models = new Dictionary\<string, List\<Tuple\<string, int\>\>\>();
models.Add("abc", new List\<Tuple\<string, int\>\>() { new("Time1", 1), new("Time2", 2), new("Time3", 3), new("Time4", 4), new("Time5",
5), new("Time6", 6) });
models.Add("adcd", new List\<Tuple\<string, int\>\>() { new("Time1", 2), new("Time2", 3), new("Time3", 4), new("Time4", 5), new("Time5",
6), new("Time6", 7) });
using SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(docName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
{
WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart\<WorksheetPart\>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    Sheet sheet = new()
    {
        SheetId = 2,
        Name = "Chart",
        Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
    };
    workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets?.AppendChild(sheet);
    var shareStringPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
    if (shareStringPart.SharedStringTable == null)
    {
        shareStringPart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
    }
    DrawingsPart drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
    
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing()
    { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
    
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
    
    ChartPart chartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
    chartPart.ChartSpace = new ChartSpace();
    chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new EditingLanguage() { Val = new StringValue("en-US") });
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = 

chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild\<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart\>(
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart());
PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild\<PlotArea\>(new PlotArea());
Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild\<Layout\>(new Layout());
var barChart = plotArea.AppendChild\<LineChart\>(new LineChart(
new Grouping() { Val = new EnumValue\<GroupingValues\>(GroupingValues.Standard) }
));
uint i = 0;
foreach (var model in models)
{
shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(model.Key)));
LineChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild\<LineChartSeries\>(new LineChartSeries(new Index()
{
Val = new UInt32Value(i)
},
new Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = model.Key })));
var strLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild\<CategoryAxisData\>(new CategoryAxisData())
.AppendChild\<StringLiteral\>(new StringLiteral());
NumberLiteral numLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild\<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values\>(
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild\<NumberLiteral\>(new NumberLiteral());
numLit.Append(new FormatCode("General"));
var index = 0U;
var xmlElementsX = new List\<OpenXmlElement\>();
var xmlElementsData = new List\<OpenXmlElement\>();
xmlElementsX.Add(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value((uint)model.Value.Count) });
xmlElementsData.Add(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value((uint)model.Value.Count) });
foreach (var item in model.Value)
{
xmlElementsX.Add(new StringPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(index), NumericValue = new NumericValue(item.Item1) });
shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Text(item.Item1)));
xmlElementsData.Add(new NumericPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(index), NumericValue = new NumericValue(item.Item2.ToString()) });
index++;
}
shareStringPart.SharedStringTable.Count = new UInt32Value((uint)model.Value.Count);
strLit.Append(xmlElementsX);
numLit.Append(xmlElementsData);
i++;
}
barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) });
barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) });
CategoryAxis catAx = plotArea.AppendChild\<CategoryAxis\>(new CategoryAxis(new AxisId()
{ Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) }, new Scaling(new Orientation()
{
Val = new EnumValue\<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues\>
(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
}),
new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue\<AxisPositionValues\>(AxisPositionValues.Bottom) },
new TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue\<TickLabelPositionValues\>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768U) },
new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue\<CrossesValues\>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
new AutoLabeled() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) },
new LabelAlignment() { Val = new EnumValue\<LabelAlignmentValues\>(LabelAlignmentValues.Center) },
new LabelOffset() { Val = new UInt16Value((ushort)100) }));
ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild\<ValueAxis\>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
new Scaling(new Orientation()
{
Val = new EnumValue\<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues\>(
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
}),
new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue\<AxisPositionValues\>(AxisPositionValues.Left) },
new MajorGridlines(),
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
{
FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)
}, new TickLabelPosition()
{
Val = new EnumValue\<TickLabelPositionValues\>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
}, new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue\<CrossesValues\>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue\<CrossBetweenValues\>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) }));
Legend legend = chart.AppendChild\<Legend\>(new Legend(new LegendPosition() { Val = new EnumValue\<LegendPositionValues\>(LegendPositionValues.Right) },
new Layout()));
chart.Append(new PlotVisibleOnly() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) });
chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();
drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.AppendChild\<TwoCellAnchor\>(new TwoCellAnchor());
twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(new ColumnId("0"),
new ColumnOffset("581025"),
new RowId("1"),
new RowOffset("114300")));
twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(new ColumnId("25"),
new ColumnOffset("276225"),
new RowId("39"),
new RowOffset("0")));
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame graphicFrame =
twoCellAnchor.AppendChild\<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame\>(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame());
graphicFrame.Macro = "";
graphicFrame.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = new UInt32Value(2u), Name = "Chart 1" },
new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties()));
graphicFrame.Append(new Transform(new Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L }, new Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L }));
graphicFrame.Append(new Graphic(new GraphicData(new ChartReference() { Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) })
{ Uri = "https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" }));
twoCellAnchor.Append(new ClientData());
drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save();
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}

I want to generate an excel with a line chart, but opening the xlsx file I generated with office excel will be fixed, causing my line chart to disappear, but I can open it normally with WPS

office excel message :Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)
